# How to extract part of pandas row as a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df, with columns like

```
['Part Number', 'Category', '1.2013', '2.2013', ... , '12.2016']
```

And other text descriptor columns.

I have the dates a list and want to extract them from an arbitrary row as a series, indexed by the dates with the old value as the series values, with no other information included.

How can I accomplish this?

EG:

My first row would be something like

```
    Category  Part Number 1.2013 2.2013 3.2013
0   Engine      RJ45          0      0      0
```

and I want

```
1.2013    0
2.2013    0
3.2013    0
Name: RJ45, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Please include the results of `print(df.head())` in the question and also hand create what a solution would look like.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [121]: df.filter(regex='^\d+\.\d{4}').T
Out[121]:
        0
1.2013  0
2.2013  0
3.2013  0
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Comment: Is there anyway to set the name of the series the same as the Part Number?

Comment: @JeremyBarnes, sorry, i'm not sure i understand what do you want to achieve... Do you want to rename the column?

Comment: I want to set the .name attribute of the series object in the column to be the same as the part number in the same row. I just can't figure out a clean way to do it without breaking the series.